# React day picker overlay always on

Tags: react-day-picker

I am using DayPickerInput and I have it set up like [this](http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/input-from-to) (Range with 2 day picker inputs). I want to always display overlay and I don't want to hide it. I am aware of `showOverlay` prop but it only displays overlay during the initial rendering and the overlay can be closed. Once closed it won't be opened by default again. Is it possible to have overlay always displayed using DayPickerInput or I should use DayPicker with my own input fields?

Answer (score 1):

This question is over 3 years old but in case someone stills looking for a way to do it now you can combine the props showOverlay and hideOnDayClick to have the overlay always on.

By doing something like this:

```
<DayPickerInput showOverlay hideOnDayClick={false} ... />
```

[source - VERSION 7.4.8](http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPickerInput)

Answer (score 0):

If you're for some reason still looking for an answer, I found another tricky way of how to always show overlay.

What I've done is:

1. Created [measuredRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) that replaces default `hideDayPicker` method with [noop](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#noop):

   ```
   const measuredRef = useCallback(node => {
     if (node !== null) node.hideDayPicker = noop
   }, [])
   ```
2. Passed this ref to `DayPickerInput` together with `showOverlay` prop:

   ```
   <DayPickerInput ref={measuredRef} showOverlay ... />
   ```

After this manipulations you'll have overlay that is always shown.

Furthermore, if you need to control `DayPickerInput` state, you can:

1. Create `useState`:

   ```
   const [isDatePickerOpen, setIsDatePickerOpen] = useState(false);
   ```
2. Use `setIsDatePickerOpen` the way you need (for example you want to hide overlay on day change):

   ```
   <DayPickerInput
     ref={measuredRef}
     showOverlay
     onDayChange={() => setIsDatePickerOpen(false)}
     ...
   />
   ```
3. Create custom `OverlayComponent`, pass it to `DayPickerInput` and control the way you show overlay:

   ```
   const OverlayComponent = ({ children, classNames, selectedDay, ...props }) => 
   (
    <div
      className={cn({
       "is-open": isDatePickerOpen,
      })}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
   )

   ------------------------------

   <DayPickerInput
     ref={measuredRef}
     showOverlay
     onDayChange={() => setIsDatePickerOpen(false)}
     overlayComponent={OverlayComponent}
     ...
   />
   ```